# htaccess wildcard redirect to query string

Tags: .htaccess

Quick question, and I've seen it asked hundreds of times, but I just can't seem to get it to work (shame on me).

I'm trying to redirect anything other than index.php to view.php?id=$1 where $1 is anything other than index.php - but I can't seem to get it to work.

For example:

http://domain.com/ should use index.php
http://domain.com/index.php as should this
but..
http://domain.com/sdgoi3 should use http://domain.com/view.php?id=sdgoi3 etc

I've tried a few things and gone down through the questions above but to no avail.

Anyone got a solution? Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php - [L]
RewriteRule ^view\.php - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The logic here is:

1. if the request URI is `/` rewrite to `index.php`
2. if the request URI starts with `index.php`, don't change and pass through
3. if the request URI starts with `view.php`, don't change and pass through
4. if the request is to a non-existing file or directory, pass to `view.php` with the id param

Comment: Thanks, this works for the wildcard but not for `http://domain.com/` etc. Also, is there a way to allow say /css/* /img/* to work normally?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^view\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

?

Comment: Edited to fix the loop on view.php.
But Jon Lin answer is probably the good one.